# Trouble communicating between two docker containers

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, spring-boot

I’m new to docker and I’m trying to connect my spring boot app running into my **boot-example** docker container to a mysql server running into my **mymysql** docker container on port 6603, both running on the same phisical machine.
The fact is: if I connect my spring-boot app to my **mymysql** docker container in order to communicate with the database, **I get no errors and everything works fine.**

When **I move my spring boot application** into my **boot-example** container and try to communicate (through Hibernate) to my **mymysql** container, then I get this error:

```
2018-02-05 09:58:38.912 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

My spring boot application.properties are:

```
server.port=8083
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:6603/mydockerdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

It works fine until my spring boot app runs in a docker container on port 8082, (after the docker image is correctly built):

```
docker run -it -p 8082:8083 boot-example
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per above suggestion, Docker-compose is a way but if you don't want to go with compose/swarm mode.

1. Simply create your own network using `docker network create myNet`
2. Deploy your containers listening on a created network `--network myNet`
3. Change your spring.datasource.url to `jdbc:mysql://mymysql:6603/mydockerdb`

By using DNS resolution of docker demon, containers can discover each other and hence can communicate.
[DNS is not supported by default bridge. A user-defined network using bridge does.]

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using network you can join two containers recognizing the same network. But what if I want just to deploy my mysql container two separate servers? I would like to connect the two containers just having their address and port like all the traditional connections.

Comment: You mean deploying MySQL container on a different server and connecting it from another container running on another server? Please clarify. :)

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use `localhost` inside the container, it's the container itself. Hence, you will always get the connection refused error.

You can do below things -

1. Add your host machine IP in `application.properties` file of your spring boot application. **(Not recommended since it breaks docker portability logic)**
2. In case you want to use `localhost`, use `--net=host` while starting the container. **(Not recommended for Production since no logical network layer exists)**
3. Use `--links` for container communication with a DNS name. **(deprecated/legacy)**
4. Create a compose file & call your DB from spring boot app with the service name since they will be in same network & highly integrated with each other. **(Recommended)**

PS - Whenever you need to integrate multiple containers together, always go for `docker-compose version 3+`. Use `docker run|build` to understand the fundamentals & performing dry/test runs.

Comment: I would suggest using links for container communication. The internal Spring Boot application.yml can be prepared to use a specific host name for the MySQL database, e.g. "jdbc:mysql://mydatabase:6603/mydockerdb".
If we want to have a local database during development there could be a special "application-dev.yml" file containing a localhost URL to the database. This configuration can be activated by enabling the "dev" Spring profile.

Comment: I've used --net=host and it works BUT... even if I map the java container as -p 8082:8083 my spring boot service is available on port 8083 and not in 8082 with the Docker port... why? Thanks!

Comment: Since your containers is launched on the host network, it uses host TCP port space to expose the service running inside the container. Docker networking doesn't work the same way when you start using `--net=host`. Think of it as another process running on your host machine without any segregated network.

Answer (score 6):

As @vivekyad4v suggested - the easiest way to achieve your desire, is to use `docker-compose` which has better container communication integration.

Docker-compose is a tool for managing single or multiple docker container/s. It uses single configuration file called `docker-compose.yml`.

For better information about docker-compose, please take a look at [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and [compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

In my experience, it is good practice to follow SRP (single responsibility principle), thus - creating one container for your database and one for your application. Both of them are communicating using network you specify in your configuration.

Following example of `docker-compose.yml` might help you:

```
version: '2'
 networks: 
 # your network name
  somename:
    driver: bridge

services:
   # PHP server
  php:
   image: dalten/php5.6-apache
   ports:
    - 80:80
   volumes:
    - .application_path:/some/application/path
   # your container network name defined at the beggining 
   networks: 
    - somename

   # Mysql server for backend
  mysql:
   image: dalten/mysql:dev
   ports:
    - 3306:3306
   # The /var/lib/mysql volume MUST be specified to achieve data persistence over container restart
   volumes:
    - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
   environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: backend
   # your container network name defined at the beggining 
   networks: 
      - somename
```

Note: Communication between containers inside network can be achieved by calling the `service name` from inside container.

The connection parameters to MySQL container from PHP, would in this example be:

```
hostname: mysql
port: 3306
database: backend
user: root
password: root
```